# SSRS adds new line when concatenating into a textbox

Tags: sql-server, wpf, reporting-services

I'm stuck here.  Everytime I concatenate SSRS textbox, the concatenation adds a new line.  I use a Microsoft SQL 2013 database.  Here is my expression that I use to concatenate.

```
=First(Fields!FirstName.Value, "DataSet1") & " " & First(Fields!LastName.Value, "DataSet1)
```

What happens is that there is a new line placed after the first name making the final output look like this.

```
FirstName

          LastName
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.  I tried googling the problem and I couldn't find an answer.  Please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was wrong.  I had to select my expression (Expr).  Then in the properties tab, I changed the Markup Type to HTML and that fixed my problem.

Thank you everyone for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable under Report/Report Properties or even concat it on the query end...it may be easier

Comment: Or even use the "join" function
Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have leading/trailing spaces. Try using `LTRIM` or `RTRIM`.

```
=First(LTRIM(RTRIM(Fields!FirstName.Value)), "DataSet1") 
 & " " & First(LTRIM(RTRIM(Fields!LastName.Value)), "DataSet1)
```